# What are the drawbacks to merging the Task and Bug Work Items and only use one of them in TFS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I was thinking that I’d rather only use the Task Work Item and ignore the Bug Work Item.  This is my thinking as I set things up for my team.  I’m on a quest to see why I shouldn’t do this.  From my perspective a Task is either a new item or a bug item.  There is no need to use two distinct Work Item Types.  To make this happen in TFS I’ll start with the Bug Work Item and create a custom field (“Item Type”) to distinguish the two task types: new/bug.  Both new tasks and bugs will share the same fields.  Anyone see any major drawbacks to this approach?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest keeping Bug and dropping Task if you want to merge them. By default when you check in code and Resolve with a bug, it sets the status to Resolved and assigns it to whoever created it - usually a tester, but in your case possibly a PM. That person can then test to confirm the work is done and close it. You can set up alerts on their work items so they get an email and know that progress has happened. Alternatively if you use Task, when you Resolve at check in it is just closed. No alerts, no further testing. YMMV but on some of our projects we use Bug for things like "user would like to add a new report" and it fits our process well. (For others we keep the distinction for reporting purposes.)

Answer (score 2):

The main reason Tasks/Issue/Bugs/etc are different work items are because the individual fields of each work type can be configured differently.

For example, by default, Bugs have a Triage property, Issues have Due date, Tasks have a Discipline. The States of a Bug (Active/Closed/Resolve) are different from an issue (Active/Closed).

By merging them into a single work item type you would loose the ability to configure each one uniquely.

Also, the rules followed when a Bug and Task are closed, for example, are generally different. Segregating them into work items allows a simpler rules set.

Work item type is also a standard column in all queries.

Overall, it depends on how extensively you are using Team Foundation. If your project is small, and the above don't matter, it's not going to hurt. Though I don't see much gain either.

Answer (score 1):

It all boils down to 3 things:

1. Creation / prioritization
2. Reporting / Notifications
3. Completion workflow

Typically creation of a Task involves different fields than a Bug.  For a bug you'll want to know things like environment found in, who notified you, severity, priority, etc.

For tasks you usually want to know the requestor, reason behind it, business unit impacted and iteration it is scheduled for.  Tasks might be long term goals that result in new or enhanced functionality.

Reporting and Notifications of the two are generally different as well.  PM's are going to track tasks to ensure deliverables are met, your tech support area is going to track bugs.

Next, bugs will generally result in hotfixes and service packs.  Depending on severity this this might involve a high priority push through QA and release as quickly as possible.  Tasks are more laid back and will go through all forms of regression and regular testing with a period of acceptance by the impacted business unit.

Finally, bugs may impact previous versions of your software.  Tasks will almost always be for either the version currently under development or the one after that.

---

In short, they are fundamentally different things.  They might share most fields in common, however by combining them you are restricting yourself in both reporting and workflows.  Today this might be okay; however within the next month or next year this could seriously restrict you.

Considering that maintainence of work item types is an incredibly easy thing there is almost no benefit to merging them.